# How do I get the input from a <textarea> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The `<textarea>` tag doesn't have an "value" attribute so, how do I get the input from it into a JavaScript variable.
For

```
<form name="myForm"> 
    <input type="text" name="aName">
</form>
```

this is quite simple:

```
var javaScriptVariable = document.myForm.aName.value;
```

But how do I get the same result using a *textarea* form?

*Note: Not interested in getting this on server side via php/perl etc.*

I know this may sound silly for many of you, but I'm at the very beginning in the world of web programming.

Comment: No one was born a web programmer :)

Comment: use id="aName" and you will get the result using document.getElementById or document.myForm.aName.value

Comment: if your problem solved, please mark one answer to accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea id="myTextArea">Value</textarea>

var textareaVal = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eDH8p/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id='wmd-input'></textarea>

var wmd = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
var input = wmd.value;
```

In the case you want to use the form object, its the same really

```
// yes, I'm testing it on this answer's form
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('inline-post')[0];
var wmd = form['post-text'];
var input = wmd.value
```

Comment: Thank you all,
Actually it works even if there isn't a value attribute associated with textarea  
There was a mistake in my script
I typed ***createNodeText()*** instead of ***createTextNode()***. Finally I catched it in console. And it works. My theory :P with value attribute doesn't stand.

Answer (score 0):

Not silly, we all have to start somewhere. Try this.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="myTextArea">
Hello world
</textarea>
```

Then to access this value:

```
var javaScriptVariable2 = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
console.log(javaScriptVariable2);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's fine

```
var txtarea document.forms["myForm"].getElementsByTagName("aName").value;

alert(txtarea)
```